# Looking for Portal solution, where each portlet can be installed on separate JVM

Tags: java, portal

We have a large portal, that consist of many applications. Applications are well encapsulated, they can exchange informations only over HTTP Session (Spring Beans, Wicket).

We have two main issues with such approach:

1. Update of single application requires restart of whole web app
2. Single application can cause instability of whole web app

Therefore we are looking for an alternative solution. We would like to deploy each application in separate Tomcat (JVM) and have a Portal that would brig all those applications together.

I was thinking about Apache Pluto, but this project is almost dead..... Lightray Portal is really active, but might be an overkill for such *simple* task.

What technology would You suggest?

Comment: We have a similar problem. We use liferay, but it's overkill for the little problem we have here. We want to unify loosely coupled applications under one user interface. Best to update each application separately and to run in its own VM. Do you have any ideas? Or for which solution have you decided?

Comment: Looks like we will implement our own portal on Angular.....

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that will make my colleagues happy.